# k8s ExternalName endpoint not found - but working

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I deployed a simple test `ingress` and an `externalName` `service` using `kustomize`.
The deployment works and I get the expected results, but when `describing` the `test-ingress` it shows the error: `<error: endpoints "test-external-service" not found>`.
It seems like a k8s bug. It shows this error, but everything is working fine.

Here is my deployment:

`kustomization.yaml`:

```yml
apiVersion: kustomize.config.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Kustomization
namespace: platform
resources:
  - test-ingress.yaml
  - test-service.yaml
generatorOptions:
  disableNameSuffixHash: true
```

`test-service.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-external-service
  namespace: platform
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: "some-working-external-elasticsearch-service"
```

`test-ingress.yaml`:

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx-external
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/configuration-snippet: |
      proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
spec:
  rules:
    - host: testapi.mydomain.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: test-external-service
              servicePort: 9200
```

Here, I connected the external service to a working `elasticsearch` server. When browsing to `testapi.mydomain.com` ("mydomain" was replaced with our real domain of course), I'm getting the well known expected `elasticsearch` results:

```json
{
  "name" : "73b40a031651",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "Xck-u_EFQ0uDHJ1MAho4mQ",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.10.1",
    "build_flavor" : "oss",
    "build_type" : "docker",
    "build_hash" : "1c34507e66d7db1211f66f3513706fdf548736aa",
    "build_date" : "2020-12-05T01:00:33.671820Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "8.7.0",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.8.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

So everything is working. But when describing the `test-ingress`, there is the following error:

`test-external-service:9200 (<error: endpoints "test-external-service" not found>)`

What is this error? Why am I getting it even though everything is working properly? What am I missing here?

Comment: After running `kubectl describe ing` command, do you have any warning/error entries in the `Events` section ? 
If you don't have any warning/error entries, everything should work as expected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is how the `kubectl describe ingress` command works.
The `kubectl describe ingress` command calls the [describeIngressV1beta1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/ac49920c0ccb0dd0899d5300fc43713ee2dfcdc9/pkg/describe/describe.go#L2623-L2672) function, which calls the [describeBackendV1beta1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/ac49920c0ccb0dd0899d5300fc43713ee2dfcdc9/pkg/describe/describe.go#L2507-L2531) function to describe the backend.

As can be found in the [source code](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/master/pkg/describe/describe.go#L2507-L2531), the [describeBackendV1beta1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubectl/blob/ac49920c0ccb0dd0899d5300fc43713ee2dfcdc9/pkg/describe/describe.go#L2507-L2531) function looks up the endpoints associated with the backend services, if it doesn't find appropriate endpoints, it generate an error message (as in your example):

```
func (i *IngressDescriber) describeBackendV1beta1(ns string, backend *networkingv1beta1.IngressBackend) string {
    endpoints, err := i.client.CoreV1().Endpoints(ns).Get(context.TODO(), backend.ServiceName, metav1.GetOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return fmt.Sprintf("<error: %v>", err)
    }
...
```

In the [Integrating External Services](https://docs.openshift.com/dedicated/3/dev_guide/integrating_external_services.html#mysql-define-service-using-fqdn) documentation, you can find that `ExternalName` services do not have any defined endpoints:

> ExternalName services do not have selectors, or any defined ports or endpoints, therefore, you can use an ExternalName service to direct traffic to an external service.

Comment: So basically you are saying, it works as expected. working, with an irrelevant error. Sounds like a bug as design :)

Comment: You are right :) I updated my first sentence to be more appropriate to the situation.

Comment: Absolutely typical Google behaviour... "This error message is a 'normal' error message, so you need to go and find the reason why you are not getting what you expected somewhere else, possibly without an associated error message anywhere"

Comment: I've submitted a small PR to clarify this in the official documentation: https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/44618
Thanks for the reference @matt_j !

Answer (score 0):

Service is a Kubernetes abstraction that uses labels to chose pods to route traffic to.

Endpoints track the IP Addresses of the objects the service send traffic to. When a service selector matches a pod label.

This is the case with Kubernetes service with the type ClusterIP, NodePort or LoadBalancer.

For your case, you use a Kubernetes service with the type ExternalName where the endpoint is a server outside of your cluster or in a different namespace, thus kubernetes displays that error message when you try to describe the ingress.

Usually we do not create an ingress that points to a service of type ExternalName because we are not supposed to expose externally a service that it is already exposed. The kubernetes ingress expects a service with the type ClusterIP, NodePort or LoadBalancer, that is why you got that unexpected error when you described the ingress.

If you are browsing that ExternalName within the cluster, it would be better to avoid using an ingress and use the service uri instead (test-external-service.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:9200)

Anyway if you insist on using the Ingress, you can create a [Headless service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) without selector and then manually create an endpoint using the same name as of the service. Follow the example [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#services-without-selectors)

Comment: As you assumed, it's a service outside the cluster, so I can't use a service URI. But if it doesn't expect an `ExternalName` type, don't let me use it. And if you do let me use it, why the error? Especially why the error if it does work as expected. Sorry, I don't understand your answer.